# Is there an App Store Info.plist size limit?

Tags: ios

Is there a limit on how big an iOS App's `Info.plist` be? I have a lot keys for a certain section of the plist, and I want to be sure that I am not rejected.

Comment: Only my opinion, but I wouldn't think a single file's size matters at all. Remember most things get compiled into binary, and then usually "thinned" when downloading to devices. What matters is the size of the entire app. Why not archive your app and see what the size of what you will upload to Apple is? Hope this link works.... https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev611e0a21f

Comment: No, but I believe excessive `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` is frowned upon.